# How does Spotlight search regex/other special characters?

Tags: spotlight, characters

I'm trying to find snippets of code in a bunch of velocity files using Spotlight (specifically pages that contain a `<html>` tag. Spotlight's missing pages that contain that tag that I know are there. Is there a way to escape characters in Spotlight? What are some good alternative search engines for Macs?

I saw this article - http://www.macworld.com/article/132788/2008/04/spotlight2.html - but it doesn't say anything about special characters, like periods or tags.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using the terminal then you could perform a grep search

example:

> grep --recursive "foo" ~/Desktop

This will provide you with a list of files containing the regex "foo".

This will only search in the Desktop folder and any subfolders.
Additionally you can use the --line-number option to also get the number of the line
which has been matched.

If you just want to find files by filename you could also use the "find" utility.

Answer (score 1):

**From the UI**

Use *Raw Queries* from the Finder advanced search (aka Spotlight window).

This was answered here:
[How to use wildcard characters in Spotlight search?](https://superuser.com/questions/28964/how-to-use-wildcard-characters-in-spotlight-search)

Jump to finder search in Finder using Command-F (or use the global shortcut Command-Option-Space). Then change the Kind to "Others > Raw Query".

```
kMDItemDisplayName==*Searchword*
```

**From the Terminal**

*mdfind*

```
mdfind "kMDItemDisplayName=='*Searchword*'c"
```

- c at the end - case-insensitive

*grep*

```
grep -iR "Searchword.*Another" ./*
```

- -i - case-insensitive
- -R - recursive search all the directories underneath
- ./* - start search at the current directory, and search all
  non-hidden files (for hidden ./.*)

*find* If you only want to search filenames

```
find . -iregex .*Searchword.*Another.*
```

*[ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep#installation)* Third party tool you can install, usually faster than grep

```
rg -i "Searchword.*Another"
```

- -i - case-insensitive