# How to search for a js file

Tags: mac, finder

Now, I know that finder has a feature to search for a specific file type like this "kind:js" however that is not turning up the right results.

Mostly that just shows files that end in .json and I cant find any of my js code even the stuff that has a known location.

`kind:` seems to only specify a search string within the file extension.

Somewhere on my computer there is a file that ends in .js but I know nothing about what the file name is or anything else of the file. How should I go about finding it?

Answer (score 1):

Per this [Superuser question](https://superuser.com/q/226566/302907), you may wish to try using `find` from the Terminal. Particularly, you may want to try something like:

```
sudo find / -name '*.js'
```

Note that this should search the entire drive. `find` is recursive by default.

If you know the location, use that instead of `/`. Similarly, you can likely drop `sudo` if you know you have the correct permissions for a given folder.

Answer (score 1):

Type `kind:js` in the Spotlight search field, then specifically choose JavaScript as the kind.

[image]