# Mac Finder saved search: how to exclude one file type?

Tags: macos, search, finder

I have a saved search for recently modified files because I wasn't satisfied with the `Recents` folder in macOS Mojave. Lately it has been getting flooded by `.tdb` files so I would like to exclude them. Is there a way to do this in a saved Finder search? You can see one thing I tried below which didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click the search attribute dropdown:

[image: other search type]

Select **Other...**

Search for **raw query** and check it:

[image: raw query search attribute]

Enter this as your raw query:

`kMDItemDisplayName!="*.tdb'c`

[image: raw query for excluding certain file types]

Additional reading:

[How do I find a file by filename in Mac OSX terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/226566/how-do-i-find-a-file-by-filename-in-mac-osx-terminal/1293358)

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/602/how-can-i-search-a-specific-type-of-file-in-mac