# How to search for file names only with wildcards in Spotlight?

Tags: iphone, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use wildcard characters in Spotlight search?](https://superuser.com/questions/28964/how-to-use-wildcard-characters-in-spotlight-search)

I have two questions about Spotlight:

1. Can Spotlight be set to not search keywords in files' contents? I just want to search the file names.
2. Can I search for wildcards, such as "`*.exe`" or "`*d.exe`" to find all the files which are ended with exe?

Answer (score 1):

The normal Spotlight UI doesn't support wildcards, but you can (almost) search by extension.

Open a Spotlight window with ⌥⌘␣ and select Filename contains (or press ⌃⌘F in Finder):

[image]

Or in the Spotlight menu:

[image]

`mdfind` does support wildcards:

```
mdfind "kMDItemFSName=='*.exe'c" # ignore case
```

Comment: For those looking for a command line, pseudo locate, add something like this to your bash initialization:
`function mdname () {
   mdfind "kMDItemDisplayName==$@"
 }`

Answer (score 1):

You can do wildcard searches using "Raw Queries" in the Finder advanced find view (aka Spotlight window). For example:
[image: Raw Query example]

More info at https://superuser.com/a/491119/66255

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this cannot be done, the only preferences for Spotlight are to change what folders to ignore, and what kind of files to search for (more broadly, images, music etc...)

**EDIT:** This can be achieved using Automator as demonstrated in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: is there any tool can achieve my purpose?

Comment: @showtimefan See edit above.